# Prove 1 is not the largest integer?

Tags: solution-verification, order-theory, fake-proofs

This proof looks extremely flawed, but I'm new to proofs so I'm not completely sure what is allowed and what isn't. Here it is:

Let $n$ be the largest positive integer. Then $n$ $\geq 1$. Multiplying both sides of the inequality by $n$ gives $n^2\geq n$. But, because $n$ is the largest possible integer, we also have $n^2\leq n$, meaning $n^2=n$. Dividing both sides by $n$ gives us $n = 1$.

I'm guessing it has something to do with the $\geq$ sign at the beginning. After all, if $n$ is the largest possible integer, then $n > 1$. But there's also the fact that there *is* no largest integer. So if I just added "$2 > 1$" to the end of the proof, wouldn't that disprove $1$ being the largest integer?

Comment: Just use Archimedes property and you get an automatic contradiction. Proof: Suppose that 1 is the largest integer. But by Archimedes property we have that there exists a natural number $n$ such that $n>1$. Hence a contradiction.

Comment: You have proven by contradiction (though with some heavy machinery, relatively speaking) that there is no largest integer.

Comment: However, for every integer $n$, $n<n+1$.

Comment: This might sound a little too simple, but what if I started with the fact that $1 > 0$, then added $n$ to both sides to get $n+1$ > $n$, meaning $n$ cannot be the largest possible integer?

Comment: @chris that'd work and be much easier

Comment: Is the proof finished?  Is it actually supposed to prove 1 IS the largest digit?  If so assuming in there is a largest digit is obviously the fault. It's so obvious it's inconceivable it'd fool anyone. I assumed it was the start of a proof by contradiction which would be fine but they never got to the proof.

Comment: It's actually what my teacher calls a "spoof," where you just try to find the flaw in the proof.

Comment: You have to prove 1 > 0 by proving x^2 > 0.  The hard part is actually knowing  what are definitions and axioms.  You can by some systems have 1>0.  But by field theory you are given m>n implies ma >na if a>0 instead and from that you prove x^2 > 0 and 1 = 1^2 (by definition).

Comment: Well, then the fault is that there is no largest integer. If there were then *any* number can be proven to be the largest.

Comment: It says, "If $n$ is the greatest integer, then $n = 1$," which is kinda like proving, "If there's a unicorn in my bathroom, then it's purple." But it doesn't mean much if there's nothing to satisfy the hypothesis. That is, the statement "If $A$ then $B$" doesn't mean a whole bunch if $A$ can't happen.

Answer (score 0):

The prove flawed in its very first line.

Let $ n $ be the largest positive integer.

How do you know a largest positive integer exists at all?

A proper proof involves a definition of integer. Without that there is no hope for a proof.

As Stephen Hawking put it, 'god created the integers', so it is actually kind of hard to have a definition of integer.

Let's start with something simpler called inductive numbers.

The set of inductive numbers $ I $ is defined as follow:

$ 1 \in I $
If $ n \in I $, then $ n + 1 \in I $.

To give the set an ordering, we define $ n + 1 > n $.

So now it is possible to create a proof that 1 is not the greatest positive integer.

1 + 1 = 2 is by definition in I and is larger than 1, so it is not the greatest positive integer.

I greatly simplified this by picking a very convenient definition. But hopefully this does point out that without a definition of integer you can't really prove anything about your proposition.

For your reference, I found this definition of integer on proof wiki.
https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Integer

Comment: This assumes 1 is *in* an inductive set. Or that inductive sets exist at all.  But it's provable that 1 >0  and it's a definition of an ordered field that if a > b then a+c > b+c.  So 1 isn't the largest is pretty dang easy to prove.

Comment: Yes. It is easy, I summarized at the end of it. The ease of proof comes ultimately from my choice of definition. The pointe I am trying to make is that in order to come up with a proof, one need a definition of the integer, and it is unclear what version of that do we want to refer to.

Comment: 'god created the integers'  — That quote is usually attributed to Leopold Kronecker (*not* Stephen Hawking).